# too many sse connections hangs the webpage

Tags: python, django, gunicorn, server-sent-events

What limits the number of SSE(server sent event) connections?

I have been working on a project using django/gunicorn/django-sse.

My project works great when i limit the number of sse connections to the page (5 works 6 hangs), this isnt a huge problem cause i use pagination so can limit the number per page. but i would prefer to be able to have as many as i like.

My question is: is it the number of connections that is slowing it down, or is it the amount of data being transfered?

the first problem i think i could fix by making them share a connection but the second would probably limit me a bit more.

Any ideas which it may be?

EDIT:

client side JS SSE code:

```
function event(url, resource_name, yes, no, audio_in, audio_out, current_draw){
    /**
     * Listens for events posted by the server
     * 
     * Useful site for understanding Server Sent Events:
     *    http://www.w3.org/TR/eventsource/
     */
    var source = new EventSource(url);
    source.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
        resetTime(resource_name);
        data = updateStatus(e.data, yes, no, audio_in, audio_out, current_draw);
        document.getElementById(resource_name+"-in").src = data.audio_in_src
        document.getElementById(resource_name+"-in").alt = data.audio_in_alt
        document.getElementById(resource_name+"-out").src = data.audio_out_src
        document.getElementById(resource_name+"-out").alt = data.audio_out_alt
        document.getElementById(resource_name+"-current").innerHTML = data.current_draw + " A"
    });
}
```

in views.py

```
class ServerSentEvent(RedisQueueView):

    def get_redis_channel(self):
        """
        Overrides the RedisQueueView method to select the channel to listen to
        """
        return self.kwargs["resource_name"]
```

in urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^$',
                           views.Resources_page.as_view(),
                           name='resources_page'),
                       url(r'^(?P<resource_name>\w+)/$',
                           views.StatusPage.as_view(),
                           name='status_page'),
                       url(r'^(?P<resource_name>\w+)/sse/$',
                           views.ServerSentEvent.as_view(),
                           name='sse'),)
```

Comment: Please post the code that is causing the problem so we can see where any problems might lie.

Comment: posted the code that deals with the SSEs

Comment: Exactly the same number was allowed for me: 5 works 6 hangs.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. I was sure I was using gevent as the worker, but I only got around 6 connections.

The solution was stupid. This was a browser limitation. I am writing it down here for the next person to stumble on this to see..

In firefox, there is a parameter in about:config that is named `network.http.max-persistent-connections-per-server` that controls this. So the solution in my case was increasing that number from 6 (default), or using several browsers..

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `sync` worker for gunicorn (the default), then you can only have as many concurrent connections to your server as you have worker processes.

The `sync` worker is designed for CPU-bound tasks, hence the recommendation to use `2N + 1` workers (where N is the number of cores available).  If your SSE endpoint is the logical equivalent of this...

```
while True:
    msg = "foo"
    yield msg
    sleep(1)
```

...then you have an I/O-bound view.  No matter how much CPU time you throw at that block of code, it's designed to never end.  If you use the `django_sse` project, then this is almost exactly [what your SSE view is doing](https://github.com/niwibe/django-sse/blob/1eedac5229e5a9128c4fbc09f7d7b97a3859e9b9/django_sse/redisqueue.py#L62).

The solution is to use an asynchronous worker class for gunicorn.  Install `gevent` and pass `--worker-class=gevent` option to gunicorn and you're on your way to an asynchronous utopia.

Comment: reasonably sure i was using gevent workers, but even when i set the number of workers >5 it was still limited to 5 connections.

Comment: @Calum: Can you spin up gunicorn with gevent workers and verify that you're still experiencing the problem?  The problem as you described it matches what you would expect from the sync worker, and you should be able to spin up many hundreds or thousands of SSE connections using a gevent worker, depending on the number of events your server sends out.

Comment: i am using gevent workers currently, the server pushes events on average of 1 event per SSE every 1-2seconds

Answer (score 0):

The browser usually limit the connections to same server, you can check that from the configuration of your browser, e.g.  in Firefox, you can check on page "about:config", where you can see such key:value { network.http.speculative-parallel-limit  6 },  of course, you can change the number to more and test.

So this is not the problem on server side.